which columns were filled with NA in rbindlist
I am using rbindlist with fill=TRUE option to fill columns with NA if a column doesn't exist.
What I want to know is which columns were filled with NA? Is there a way to return the missing columns?
code
df1 <- data.frame(a = 1:2, b = 3:4)
df3 <- data.frame(a = 9:10)

result <- rbindlist(list(df1, df3), fill = TRUE)

output
    a  b
1:  1  3
2:  2  4
3:  9 NA
4: 10 NA

I want to know that column b is missing from df3

It's easier to help you if you include a simple reproducible example with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. It is unlikely that you can get this information from rbindlist, you'll probably want to just change the name before combining.

@MrFlick what do you mean by change the name before combining? how does that help?

Get all the names from list of data.tables, then loop and get difference, try this example:
library(data.table)

#example data
dlist <- list(data.table(x=1, y=2),
              data.table(x=11, y=22, z=33))

rbindlist(dlist, fill = TRUE)
#        x     y     z
#    <num> <num> <num>
# 1:     1     2    NA
# 2:    11    22    33


allCols <- unique(unlist(lapply(dlist, names)))

lapply(dlist, function(i) setdiff(allCols, names(i)))
# [[1]]
# [1] "z"
# 
# [[2]]
# character(0)


You could use the waldo package
df1 <- data.frame(a = 1:2, b = 3:4)
df3 <- data.frame(a = 9:10)

result <- data.table::rbindlist(list(df1, df3), fill = TRUE)

waldo::compare(df3$a, result$b)


old: 9 10
new: 3  4 NA NA

